# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throws an exception when deserializing JSON with a hex value into an sbyte property

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json.net, jsonconverter

I have a machine-generated class `MyData` which has `sbyte` members.  The actual class is long and not very readable, but here is a fragment of it:

```
class MyData
{
    private sbyte _MuxControl;
    public sbyte MuxControl 
    { 
        get { return _MuxControl; } 
        set { __isset.MuxControl = true; this._MuxControl = value; }
    }
}
```

The corresponding simplified JSON looks like this:

```
[ 
  { 
    "MuxControl": 0xAA
  }
]
```

I am attempting to deserialize like this:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyData>>(JsonStr);
```

Some values exceed `sbyte` range, for example `0xAA`. As a result, exceptions are thrown.  When I change the value to `0x1`, for example, it works.

I can not touch the code of `MyData`.  It's machine-generated.  Is there a conversion setting, override or some other way to get these values to deserialize properly into `sbyte`?

Comment: Can you share the JSON you are trying to deserialize, the definition of `MyData` and the desired treatment when one of the values is out of range?

Comment: @BrianRogers Sure. As I wrote, `MyData` is machine-generated, so, long and unreadable. I can share fragment of it:
`private sbyte _MuxControl;`

`public sbyte MuxControl
    {
      get
      {
        return _MuxControl;
      }
      set
      {
        __isset.MuxControl = true;
        this._MuxControl = value;
      }
    }`
 
Json has something `"MuxControl": 0xAA,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the exception because the conversion methods Json.Net is using under the covers for `sbyte` are range checked, but what you really need here is an unchecked conversion (or more precisely, a bigger range).  You can handle that with a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) like so:

```
public class SByteConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(sbyte);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer)
        {
            // Integer values come in as longs from the reader.
            long val = (long)reader.Value;

            // If the value fits in 8 bits, convert it to a signed byte.
            if (val >= -128 && val <= 255)
            {
                return unchecked((sbyte)val);
            }

            // We got a value that can't fit in an sbyte.
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Value was out of range for an sbyte: " + val);
        }

        // We got something we didn't expect, like a string or object.
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected token type: " + reader.TokenType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Write sbyte values out in the same format we read them.
        // Note this is technically invalid JSON per the spec.
        writer.WriteRawValue("0x" + ((sbyte)value).ToString("X2"));
    }
}
```

To use the converter, pass an instance of it to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` like this:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyData>>(JsonStr, new SByteConverter());
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fEW6wy

Comment: Shouldn't it be +127 for sbyte (Or sbyte.MinValue/sbyte.MaxValue) ?

Comment: @ivo Normally, yes.  But the whole problem we are trying to solve here is to allow values that are *above* 127, but still fit in 8 bits, such as 170 (0xAA) to be cast to an `sbyte` per the OP's requirements.   The `unchecked` keyword allows us to do that without throwing an exception.  I opted to leave the lower end of the range as -128 instead of 0 just in case there happened to be `sbyte` values in the data other than `MuxControl` which were represented as negative integers.  I wanted to allow those to still convert normally.

Comment: Ah, yes. now it makes sense. Thank you very much for clarifying this